# Wp-admin widgets have no title texts

Tags: wp-admin, widgets

In wp-admin when I enter widgets I see their bars, but the titles of widgets are missing. only :Something remain visible and the others are gone.

What happened? How do I fix that?

Edit:

Found it in wp-admin/includes/widgets.php

line that was

`<div class="widget-title"><h4><?php $widget_title ?><span class="in-widget-title"></span></h4></div>`

should be

`<div class="widget-title"><h4><?php echo $widget_title ?><span class="in-widget-title"></span></h4></div>`

Is that a wordpress bug or somebody on my team had to edit this? [noone takes the blame ;)]

Comment: Highly unlikely that some code changed core WP file, so must be person. I think question is safe to nuke?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, I took a look in the actual source code of the WordPress repository.  The line in question is:

```
<div class="widget-title"><h4><?php echo $widget_title ?><span class="in-widget-title"></span></h4></div>
```

I also went through and checked previous changesets to see if we ever accidentally released broken code.  If you want to look at the revision log yourself, it's [freely available on Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/log/trunk/wp-admin/widgets.php).

But the long story made short is that you weren't seeing a WordPress bug.  Someone on your team would have had to explicitly made that change ... even if they weren't willing to take the blame.

All the more reason you should be keeping everything under source control.  Then you'd know exactly who made the change, when, and possibly have some idea as to why.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I'm glad it turned out that way. And as for the source control - the site was already in testing when that happened. I have no idea how. That's why I blamed an update.